# IE custom 404 error page not working jsp

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, error-handling, custom-error-pages

I am trying to put custom 404 error page ....it works fine with chrome and firefox, but with IE it is displaying its own error page.

I got to know that in IE if you uncheck "Show friendly Error Message" then it displays my custom error page.

but I can't say every user to please uncheck it...:)

In such case how to display custom error page.

Also, is there any direct solution through which this can be achieved.

there must be something i am missing, because when i open google.com/aaa then instead of "Show friendly Error Message" checked, it displays google custom error page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're on an Apache server, you could use a ".htaccess" file. If you've never done this before here's one easy way: open a text editor, create a new file and give it this line:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
```

Then save the file somewhere handy as "htaccess" (without the preceding period). Then upload it to your root directory and rename it to ".htaccess" (add the preceding period, no file extension).

This directive tells Apache to serve "notfound.html" via the path specified whenever Apache cannot find the file it needs (i.e. "google.com/aaa"). Place "notfound.html" also in the root directory (or if you want it in a different directory, just change the path to something like "/other-directory/notfound.html").

Hope that helps.

Comment: You might want to check the following article from ms about the subject http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294807

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the server you are using.

One important point is to make sure that your error page is at least 512 byes in size. IE substitutes it's own error message if the error page is less than 0.5kB in size.

If you are serving from an IIS server, you need to enable the Custom ASP Errors feature.